# How to save tokens in an integer array?

Tags: java

I was trying to save the following line into different arrays:

```
1908,Souths,Easts,Souths,Cumberland,Y,14,12,4000
```

The code I am using gives me integer values for `year[i]` but gives me zero values for `winningScore[i]`, `loosingScore[i]` and `crowd[i]`. Can anyone help me please? My code is as follows:

```
str[i] = inputFile.nextLine();
StringTokenizer tok = new StringTokenizer(str[i], ",");

while (tok.hasMoreTokens()) {   
    year[i] = Integer.parseInt (tok.nextToken());
    winteam[i] = tok.nextToken();    
    loosingteam[i] = tok.nextToken();
    minor[i] = tok.nextToken();
    wooden[i] = tok.nextToken();
    held[i] = tok.nextToken();
    if(held[i] == "Y") {
        winningScore[i] = Integer.parseInt (tok.nextToken()); 
        loosingScore[i] = Integer.parseInt (tok.nextToken());
        crowd[i] = Integer.parseInt (tok.nextToken());
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this a homework assignment? :-)

Answer (score 2):

`==` is use for equaling two reference and `Object#equals` method is use for equaling two `Object`.

`if(held[i] == "Y")` String equaling need to do with equals method like

```
if(held[i].equals("Y")){...}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Subhrajyoti Majumder. It works now. Thanks again.